# DNN - ContactUS - Email not triggering

Tags: smtp, dotnetnuke

DNN - ContactUS - Email not triggering

I am able to test SMTP-test mail successfully in my site (Host Settings) ,
But 
In the Contact us page.. while submitting am not receiving it to my mailBox . I have updated EmailTo in ModuleSetting table, still :(
Is there anywhere any boolean to decide , whether it should trigger or not . 
Can you suggest the possibilities of this issue

Rigin

Answer (score 0):

Check the Event Log to see if there are messages regarding mail delivery issues.

Often, the server's SMTP server is set up to NOT relay for an out of domain address.  If so, this will require proper configuration of the SMTP server.